# R p-value half to SPSS rANOVA

Tags: r, anova, spss, p-value

I have done rANOVA in SPSS and then in R and got two different p-values from the same model. While SPSS gives 0.032, R gives 0.0162, which when rounded is a half. Other data are exactly the same.

**1. Why?**

Intuitively, one of them does a one-tailed, the other a two-tailed test. Other values are: Sum Sq `19.071` (SPSS) v. `24.14` (R) or F value `4.863` (SPSS) v. `6.156` (R).

Other parts of the table are the same though, both `IV1 * IV2` and `residuals`.

**2. Why? Which is *“more correct”*?**

**3. How to get the SPSS-reported values from R?**

SPSS approach:

```
Analyze –> General Linear Model –> Repeated Measures…
```

R approach:

```
summary(aov(DV ~ IV1 * IV2 + Error(subject/(IV1 * IV2)), data))
```

**Update to answer @PeterFlom and give additional details:**

I am evaluating *the effect of an intervention (treatment: a lecture) on the ability to spot behavioral clues of emotions using visual stimuli* using **pretest-posttest plus control group** experimental design.

The experimental group is given the first set of stimuli, then there is intervention and the second set of stimuli follows. Naturally, the same without the intervention occurs in the case of the control group. **Two groups, two measurements each.**

The **hypothesis** is that the intervention significantly raises the ability to spot behavioral clues of emotions.

SPSS calculates the same interaction too.

The data:

```
    subject   group   phase     value
1        A1     exp     pre        13
2        A2     exp     pre         7
.
35       B1    cont     pre         9
36       B2    cont     pre        14
.
57       A1     exp    post        11
58       A2     exp    post        12
.
91       B1    cont    post        13
92       B2    cont    post        12
```

Honestly, I am using it as is because a tutorial said so. I have got a very shallow understanding of the correct process in R.

**Update in response to @ttnphns:**

SPSS data:

```
group    pre    post
  exp     13      11
  exp      7      12
 cont      9      13
 cont     14      12
```

SPSS commands:

```
GET DATA 
  /TYPE=TXT 
  /FILE="F:\file.csv" 
  /DELCASE=LINE 
  /DELIMITERS=";" 
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED 
  /FIRSTCASE=2 
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL 
  /VARIABLES= 
  group A4 
  pre F2.0 
  post F2.0. 
CACHE. 
EXECUTE. 
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT. 
GLM pre post BY group 
  /WSFACTOR=phase 2 Polynomial 
  /METHOD=SSTYPE(3) 
  /PLOT=PROFILE(phase*group) 
  /PRINT=DESCRIPTIVE ETASQ 
  /CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05) 
  /WSDESIGN=phase 
  /DESIGN=group.
```

Comment: Just at a glance, it looks like you are assuming repeated measures in `SPSS` but not in `R`; in `R` you've included the interaction between IV 1 and 2, did you do that in `SPSS`.  What data have you got, and what are your hypotheses and research questions? Do you have repeated measures? I am also not sure what the "Error(subject..." does; `R` help says it "specifies error strata" but it's unclear to me why you are using it the way you are, here.

Comment: @PeterFlom Give me a moment, please. I shall update the question as per your request.

Comment: @PeterFlom Done.

Comment: Why don't you give some data and SPSS command, too?

Comment: @ttnphns Done now.

Comment: Note that the design in unbalanced (34 experimental v. 22 control) and I have found similar problems being caused by `aov()` not using `Type-III SS`, but I am not sure and going to try alternative functions.

Comment: If you type ?aov in `R` you will see that it should not be used for unbalanced designs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you indicated in the comments, SS type I (`aov()`) vs. III (SPSS) is indeed one reason for the different results. The other reason is that your formula for `aov()` is incorrect, as the `Error()` term you used is the for two crossed within factors - whereas you have one between (`group`) and one within (`phase`) factor. Here's a reproducible example on how to replicate the results from SPSS in R. First SS type I with `aov()`:

```
set.seed(23)         # make reproducible
Nj  <- c(22, 34)     # number of subjects in control and experimental group (unbalanced)

# data frame long format -> make sure subject, group and phase are factors
dfL <- data.frame(subject=factor(rep(1:sum(Nj), times=2)),
                  group=factor(rep(rep(c("A", "B"), times=Nj), time=2)),
                  phase=factor(rep(1:2, each=sum(Nj))),
                  value=round(rnorm(2*sum(Nj), rep(c(-0.5, 0.5), each=sum(Nj)), 2), 3))

summary(aov(value ~ group*phase + Error(subject/phase), data=dfL))
```

results in:

```
Error: subject
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
group      1   0.81   0.812   0.198  0.658
Residuals 54 221.72   4.106               

Error: subject:phase
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
phase        1  29.04  29.040   8.747 0.00459 **
group:phase  1   5.80   5.799   1.747 0.19188   
Residuals   54 179.28   3.320
```

Now SS type III using `Anova()` from package `car`. Make sure to use effect coding instead of treatment coding as SS type III requires this.

```
# effect coding
options(contrasts=c(unordered="contr.sum", ordered="contr.poly"))

# data frame in wide format
dfW <- reshape(dfL, direction="wide", v.names="value", timevar="phase",
               idvar=c("subject", "group"))

library(car)   # for Anova()
fitSPFpq   <- lm(cbind(value.1, value.2) ~ group, data=dfW)
inSPFpq    <- data.frame(phase=gl(2, 1))
AnovaSPFpq <- Anova(fitSPFpq, idata=inSPFpq, idesign=~phase, type="III")
summary(AnovaSPFpq, multivariate=FALSE, univariate=TRUE)
```

gives

```
Univariate Type III Repeated-Measures ANOVA Assuming Sphericity

                 SS num Df Error SS den Df      F  Pr(>F)  
(Intercept)  1.7844      1   221.72     54 0.4346 0.51256  
group        0.8118      1   221.72     54 0.1977 0.65834  
phase       22.5410      1   179.28     54 6.7896 0.01182 *
group:phase  5.7985      1   179.28     54 1.7466 0.19188
```

... the same as SPSS.

Answer (score 1):

Harold,  Not sure if this is why the difference, but I note that in SPSS you specify METHOD=SSTYPE(3).  In base R, the default is a type 1. You will need to load a different package than base in order to estimate type 3.

Comment: Could you please suggest a way of doing so? I have tried `car::Anova()` with no success as I am unable to use the same model (`DV ~ IV1 * IV2 + Error(subject/(IV1 * IV2))`).

Comment: Okay, here we go (all credit to R in Action by Robert Kabacoff).  In type I (R default) effects are adjusted for those that appear earlier in the formula. In Type III (SPSS default) each effect is adjusted for every other effect; including interaction effects. The Anova() function in the car package provides the option of using all three types (I, II, or III). Load the car package. When in R, type: help(Anova, package="car"). Note that this is Anova() and not anova() or aov().  Hope this helps.

Comment: I was aware of that function, even tried it—the problem was with using the same linear model. Thanks for your time.